# Bootstrap card images disappear on tablets only

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

My website is working perfectly on desktop and mobile devices, however when I view my website on a tablet/ipad my card images disappear. I can't seem to figure out why as I'm using Bootstrap 4/MDBootstrap and it is naturally responsive. I've never had this happen before. I have a feeling it's something simple I'm missing but can't find it. Also I don't have a custom CSS file. I'm using the CSS that MDBoostrap offers. I only made minor changes and those are made within the HTML file. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">

      <!--Card-->
      <div class="card">

        <!--Card image-->
        <div class="view overlay"> 
          <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <a href="http://www.eddiearkmunoz.com/" target="_blank"> 
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>                
          </a> 
        </div>

        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">Mu&ntilde;oz Designs</h4>
          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text"><b>Languages:</b> HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, JavaScript, PHP</p>
          <a href="http://www.eddiearkmunoz.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn" style="background-color: #1C2331;">View</a> 
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--/.Card--> 

    </div>
    <!--Grid column-->

    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">

      <!--Card-->
      <div class="card">

        <!--Card image-->
        <div class="view overlay"> 
          <img src="img/work2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
          <a href="http://www.ridewithamy.info/" target="_blank">                    
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>                
          </a> 
        </div>

        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">Ride with Amy</h4>

          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text"><b>Languages:</b> HTML, CSS, MDBootstrap, Javascript</p> 
          <a href="http://www.ridewithamy.info/" target="_blank" class="btn btn" style="background-color: #1C2331;">View</a> 
        </div> 

      </div>
      <!--/.Card--> 

    </div>
    <!--Grid column-->

    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">

      <!--Card-->
      <div class="card">

        <!--Card image-->
        <div class="view overlay"> 
          <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
          <a href="#">                    
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>                
          </a> 
        </div>

        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">WIP</h4>
          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text"> This WordPress website is being created for personal study. </p> 
          <a href="#" class="btn btn" style="background-color: #1C2331;">View</a> 
        </div> 

      </div>
      <!--/.Card--> 

    </div>
    <!--Grid column-->

  </div>
  <!--Grid row-->
```

Comment: There is no longer `-xs` in Bootstrap 4. [Read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Hi Zim, it's funny you said that because it was originally at md and it was working so I tried xs. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Alexandra Itz working fine to ipad

Comment: Everyone keeps telling me it's working on ipads. So i'm assuming it's my ipad that's not functioning correctly. ?